# How are number of flags available calculated?

Tags: support, flagging

When I first started flagging, I had something to the tune of 10 flags available.

Over time, I've seen this number increase. I currently have 39 total available (I've already got a couple open at the time of this screenshot).

What controls this number/limit?

[image: flag modal]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [flag privilege page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) says:

> #### How many flags do I have?
>
> When you start out, you are allotted 10 flags per day. This number may increase to up to 100 flags per day:
>
> - You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation.
> - You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly - one bonus flag for every ten net helpful flags (helpful flags minus declined flags).